How to define yourself the names of auto generated OpenAPI classes
I am generating API classes from spec using openapitools.
<groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
<artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>7.4.0</version>

For the following two definitions it generates an ItemsApi with getItems and getItemsClean
  /items/{itemName}:
    get:
      operationId: getItems 
      parameters:
        - name: itemName
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The name of an item
          schema:
            type: string

  /items/{itemName}/clean/
    get:
      operationId: getItemsClean
      parameters:
        - name: itemName
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The name of an item
          schema:
            type: string


So whatever I add to the path after /items all endpoints going to land in ItemsApi.
It is possible to define the generated Api class yourself?
Adding a tag does not help.

In your plugin put the following config:
<configOptions>
 <useTags>true</useTags>
</configOptions>

And then use tags in the yaml like so:
/items/{itemName}:
    get:
      tag: Something
      operationId: getItems 
      parameters:
        - name: itemName
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The name of an item
          schema:
            type: string

